# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - when using library from another solution

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I'm using library to access a service on an https address.
I've written a tester (in the same solution) and everything works ok.

now i've added my library as a reference to another project (ast.net web) 
and when I call the same method I get this as a response from the server.

ERROR: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel./n

the only difference is that my library is not in the solution but rather referenced.

What can be the issue and how can I resolve it ?
I know I can disable the check - but the server is OK, it's something in my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Solved this. 
Apparently the project used different defaults. not sure why.